# Get color from custom Assets.xcassets file

Tags: swift, xcode, assets

I have a separate `DesignSystem` package in my project.
In that package, I created new `Assets.xcassets` and added some colours with appropriate names there.
Now I want to reach that colours from the same package using the name:
I am trying:

```
let name = "myImageName"
let color = Color(name)
let uiColor = UIColor(named: name)
```

But none of them works.

My Idea is that, since I am using a separate Package and I have created a new custom `Assets.xcassets` then I have to specify some path in the name of configuring something.

The same problem exists with other assets, like Image.

Using XCode: 14.3

Comment: There are versions of the initialisers that allow a bundle to be specified: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/2877381-init. But if you are trying to access the color from the package that contains the assets, I would expect the simpler initialiser would work. Are the assets really built into the package correctly?

Comment: Hi Georff, thanks for the comment. I have tried initializer with Bundle, but I had the same result.

What do you mean in `correctly building the assets`?.

I have simple created new `.xcassets` file and named it `Assets` and places some Colors inside that resources.

Comment: I meant that the asset catalog is built as part of the separate package and if you are using Swift Package Manager that the assets are included in that target (I don’t know how to do that but I think it has to be done to include them as part of the package’s resources)

Comment: Yes, it is done.
To do so, you can add `resources: [.process("Resources")]` in the target of Package file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since resources are in the module and not in the main bundle, you have to write it explicitly:

```
Color(name, bundle: .module)
```